# How to simplify nested array in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have python array like this,

```
list = [[[['01/01/2015', ' Born']]], [[['05/05/2014', ' Marriage']]], [[['01/01/2009', ' Winnings']]]]
```

How to simplify this list. I want in the following format,

```
list = [['05/05/2014', ' Marriage'],['05/05/2014', ' Marriage'],['01/01/2009', ' Winnings']]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
transformed_list = [item[0][0] for item in list]
```